# Django Directory Structure - Non-website code

Tags: django

I have a Django project that includes code for processes that are scheduled to run (via cron) independently from the website.  The processes update the database using the models from one of my apps so I guess the code for these processes could be considered part of that app even though it's not part of the website.  Should I create a package inside the app directory to hold these modules?

Answer (score 3):

If the code you're supposed to run is tied to models in a certain app, you can write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/) for it.

The code lives inside your app (in `myapp/management/commands/command_name.py`) and you'll be able to call it using `manage.py` or `django-admin.py`, which allows you to add an entry to cron very easily.